# Firebase data class for retreiving string or int or both

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have developed an app in which I am retrieving data from Firebase with the help of data class. Problem is the data which I am retrieving can be either String or numbers (int or long) or a combination of both. I have declared the variables inside data class as a String type, so it works fine for String data retrieval but the app crashes when I try to retrieve numbers. This is the data class

```
public class Choices {

    private String a, b, c, d;

    public Choices() {
    }

    public Choices(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

I Just want to know is there any way through which I can design the data class in such a way that it can handle both String and numerical data.

Comment: Every thing non primitive is a decendent of Object so you could use that instead of String. While ints and longs are primitive, java will autobox/unbox to Integer/Long types.

Comment: So you mean to say I should change String type to Object type in the above code

Comment: While I don't know much about firebase. Yes, everything can be set to Object... you'll have to do some sort of instanceof check and then cast to your type later probably...

Comment: If you're seeing a crash, always post the stack trace along with the code that crashes, and the line where it crashes.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace and your code where you are getting the data.